# Как получить View во фрагменте, если View инициализирован в Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Для простоты понимания буду спрашивать на примере `FloatigActionButton`. Допустим, мы объявили и проинициализировали `FAB` в `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    }

}
```

Как нам обратиться к этой кнопке из класса-фрагмента?

Пробовал создать метод:

```
public FloatingActionButton getFab(){
    return fab;
}
```

Чтобы вызвать этот метод, мы должны создать экземпляр `MainActivity` в классе фрагмента. Это не получится сделать следующим образом:

```
MainActivity activity = getActivity();
```

Вообщем, тут уже сводится к вопросу "Как правильно обратиться к активности из фрагмента", что претендует на отдельную тему. Но возможно, есть какие-то другие пути обращения к созданной в Activity кнопке fab.

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы обратиться к активности из фрагмента вам необходимо привести результат `getActivity()` к типу данной активности:

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
```

далее вы можете обращаться к вашему методу:

```
public FloatingActionButton getFab(){
    return fab;
}
```

Comment: Благдарю Вас за ответ! А идея получения `fab` из `MainActivity` была правильной или обычно это по-другому делается?

Comment: часто объявляют интерфейс и через него из фрагментов и других частей получают доступ, также через интерфейс получают взаимодействие между фрагментами на одной активности, а так все вполне корректно.